# How to use 2 connections in one bundle with mapping?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two connections in config. And one of my bundles will use them together, but how i can specify which is used by entity class in that class?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if one of your bundle will use one connection and another bundle will use the other one. Because you talking about class in your question:

> ... but how i can specify which is used by entity class in that class?

I will assume that one of your bundle which has entities will use a specific connection to map those entities to your database. To do this, you should provide the connection key in your configuration, something like this:

```
doctrine:
    default_connection:   default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        other:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default # The default entity manager if you specify more than one
        entity_managers:
            default:
                # The name of a DBAL connection (the one marked as default is used if not set)
                connection: other
                mappings: # Required
                    AcmeHelloBundle: ~
                    # You can specify more bundle here
```

Moreover, I think it is even possible to specify specific classes as a list below the node `AcmeHelloBundle`. You will need to investigate this further to see if it possible.

You can check the doctrine configuration reference [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) for more configuration options for doctrine.

Hope this helps and that was what you were looking for.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: I need to use 2 entityManagers in one Action. Suppose I have 2 entity classes - __Entity/User.php__ and __Entity/Post.php__ . How to specify in __User.php__ that it must use **Default** connection, and __Post.php__ must use **Other**?

Comment: "I think it is even possible to specify specific classes as a list below the node AcmeHelloBundle" - I've been trying to accomplish this, but have been unable to. I'm curious if you have this working somehow?